# Why intrinsic lock like synchronized is discouraged

Tags: java, multithreading

For thread safety, we can use **synchronized** keyword or we can use Reentrant Lock in java. But why Architects persuade not to use **synchronized** keyword. I want to know how JVM treats the **synchronized** keyword internally as a result we may suffer performance issue. Please suggest me.

Comment: It's a coding issue concerned with scoping. Not an architectural issue in any way shape or form.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate one, my question is not related to advantages of ReentrantLock over synchronized keyword, the question was how JVM treats synchronized keywords as a result we may suffer performance issue. Again the question what is the underlying issue with the usage of synchronized keyword in JLS.

Comment: Your question is not a question about the Java language or its standard libraries:  It is a question about some _particular implementation_ of the language and its libraries.  There is nothing in the Java language spec that requires a `synchronized` block from being more or less performant than a `ReentrantLock`, and there is nothing in the spec that prevents it either.  Probably the best thing for you to do is measure the performance yourself, on the platform in question.